# DRF File Upload, How can I solve File missing Error?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
400 Error

{"detail":"Missing filename. Request should include a Content-Disposition header with a filename parameter."}
```

I want to upload file via DRF FileUploadParser
But Error occurs below

```
Bad Request: /api/activities/40/chapter/1/upload
[09/Nov/2021 16:44:33] "POST /api/activities/40/chapter/1/upload HTTP/1.1" 400 109
```

And my codes in `views.py` about that error are this.

```
class FileView(APIView):

    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)

    def post(self, request,  format=None, *args, **kwargs):

        if 'file' not in request.FILES:
            raise ParseError("Empty content")

        f = request.FILES.get('file')
        print(f)
        print(dir(request))
        print(request.__dict__)

        addAttr = request.data.dict()
        file_name = request.data['filename']
        
        new_file_full_name = file_upload_path(file_name.name)
        file_path = '/'.join(new_file_full_name.split('/')[0:-1])

        #model Attr
        addAttr['activityid'] = request.parser_context['kwargs']['pk']
        addAttr['chapterid'] = request.parser_context['kwargs']['chapterid']
        addAttr['filepath'] = file_path
        addAttr['filename'] = file_name
        addAttr['fileext'] = os.path.splitext(file_name.name)[1]
        addAttr['create_date'] = datetime.datetime.now()

        addAttrDict = QueryDict('', mutable=True)
        addAttrDict.update(addAttr)

        fileSerializer = ChapterfileSerializer(data = addAttrDict, files=request.FILES)
        if fileSerializer.is_valid():
            
            fileSerializer.save()       
            print(fileSerializer.data)
                    
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            print(fileSerializer.errors)
            return Response(fileSerializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

If I add a parameter "filename", 500 error occured.

```
TypeError: post() missing 1 required positional argument: 'parameter'
[09/Nov/2021 16:48:35] "POST /api/activities/40/chapter/1/upload HTTP/1.1" 500 86716
```

ReactJS page sends File to my Django API Server.

activityid and chapterid are Board and Post ID.
SO, I need these insert to DB.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Could you please, post the model and serializer code. It would help to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Use the FileUploadParser, it's all in the request. Use a put method instead, you'll find an example in the docs :)

```
 class FileUploadAPIView(views.APIView):
    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)

    def put(self, request, filename, format=None):
        file_obj = request.FILES['file']
        # Do some stuff with the uploaded file
        return Response({'details': 'Your file uploaded successfully.'}, status=204)
```